# Can I put the same Controller into several files in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, architecture, controller

Initial situation in a new Project: It is about a Controller, which is used in many many views (grown historically) and these are wildly distributed. The Controller has 10.000++ Lines.

Instead of creating new Controllers and implementing it in the existing views, I want to seperate the same Controller (e.g. TheOneAndOnlyController.js) into several files, so that several persons can work somehow independently (offline).

Questions:

1. Is it a good idea?
2. How should I do that efficiently?

---

P.s. I didn't think that up myself..

Comment: I would just run as far as I could :)

Comment: Sounds like a REALLY bad idea to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem when Controller starts to grow too much.
My recommendation is to split the Controller into a smaller modular Services. I'm sure there are places in the controller where it can be done easily.
If the code is tied up with the view and cannot refactor to a Service, try to create independent Directives.
Please check this [link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#defer-controller-logic-to-services) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

yes its a very good idea instead of not just separating the ctrl , i will recommend to create some new module for each view and different ctrl for each view , also you can move the code which do not uses $scope to the service to optimize your code for best result .